# Is this automatic and mechanical water dispenser an open- or closed-loop system?

Tags: control, control-system

I am starting my introduction phase to the course of Feedback and Control systems as a current undergraduate of Computer Engineering. We were tasked to determine the type of control system this water dispenser (see image below) represents and how the block diagram should look like. The image in question is this:

[image: automatic, ancient, and mechanical water dispenser]

My initial response was that it was a closed loop system because the output of the system (the cup getting filled) affects the control mechanism of the contraption, which either opens or closes the valve inside the jug. In essence since the output is measured (weight) and compared to an initial input weight (see the small weight in the other end of the horizontal stick?) and there exists a difference in output and input, then the system notices this and continues to output water. Is my reasoning and answer correct?

Comment: Yes. The reasoning is correct.

Comment: Agreed. But John. You should insist that the instructor bring in this device. ;) Lines on a piece of paper can be misinterpreted or may represent an [impossible device](https://mcescher.com/gallery/impossible-constructions/). Say you aren't obsessive-compulsive, but that you just like to double-check your work before handing it in.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's a closed loop P-controller. The levers are feedback/gain. However this depiction makes impossible to tune the proportional gain. The system itself is an integrator. Therefore, the open loop response is the integrator, while the closed loop response is 1st order lag.

The bottom balance is the difference amplifier: cup weight - fixed weight, you can change the setpoint value by moving the fixed weight. The difference moves the lever l, which in turn moves another balance mechanism : P-controller. The gain is a factor of levers length left VS. right side of the fixed joint (attached to main bottle). You could adjust the proportional gain by moving the lever l more left, additional holes would be needed on upper balance.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fMMjHj.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

More exactly there should be a diode like element following the difference, since there is no possible that water could go back from a cup to the bottle. If the cup is overfilled, it will remain overfilled.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fMb9oZ.png)</sup>